# OOP PHP taking content from forms created by a loop

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm using OOP PHP right now, and I created a few functions that pass data from a form and insert them into the database. I know all those functions work properly, but the forms in a loop wont seem to be pass.

Here's an example of how it looks:

```
 //Input class://
    <?php
class Input{

  public static function exists($type='post'){
    switch($type){
      case 'post':
        return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
      break;
      case 'get':
        return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
      break;
      default:
      return false;
      break;
    }
  }

  public static function get($item){
if(isset($_POST[$item])){
  return $_POST[$item];
}else if(isset($_GET[$item])){
  return $_GET[$item];
}
    return '';
  }
}

 ?>
```

//----------------------------------//

```
<?php  $user = new User();
    $user_id = $user->data->id; ?>
```

//some html//

```
     <?php

                 foreach($products->results() as $row){
                       $pid = $row->id;
                       $product = $row->product;
                       $days = $row->days_default;
                       $description = $row->description;
                       $img = $row->img_address;
                       $category = $row->category;
                       $x++;
        ?>


<h4 class="item-title"><?php echo $product . $pid?></h4>
<h5 class="item-subtitle"><?php echo $category ?></h5>

<span class="timing"><?php echo $days . " days" ?></span>

<div class="itme-description"><?php echo $description ?></div>
<div>
  <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value= "<?php $pid ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="days" id="days" value="<?php $days ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php $user_id ?>">
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
</div>

     <?php  

     if(Input::exists()){
              $reminder = new Reminder();

               try{
                 $reminder->create(
                    array(  'product_id'=>Input::get('product_id'),
                            'days'=>Input::get('days'),
                            'user_id'=> Input::get('user_id')));
                            }catch(exception $e){
                              die($e->getMessage());}
                            }

     }  


     ?>
```

I can't figure out how to pass the individuals forms to the server when the user hits submit.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm honestly not getting any, but nothing is being submitted. It's as if when I hit the submit button, the program just refreshes the page.

Comment: I don't see how this code can run,  $user = new User(); and $user_id = $user->data->id; are outside of the starting <?php tag.  your $reminder->create is part of the loop that displays the page which doesn't make sense.  Can you provide the code for the Input class or link to it?

Comment: The $user = new User();
$user_id = $user->data->id; Is actually inside a <?php ?>, that's just a type from it sitting further up the page.

The input class has been added.

Comment: I've tried placing the call to the reminder->create method above the loop, and that also didn't work. When I pass the values in without the loop, I'm able to create the reminders in the database.